# Manually performing linear regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

Suppose I have the following linear model.

*y = ax + bz*

My question is; how to I estimate these parameters without using the lm function.

Comment: you already did that in your formula

Comment: @GuedesBF, I agree the question could be improved with more specifics. I think the poster, as a new contributor, probably is asking for how to estimate those parameters. Is that right, WHN Zijpp van der?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how strict you want to be with the no package requirement. If you are willing to use the `stats` package (which most people don't really even think of as a package because it comes standard with base R and you don't have to load it with `library()`), then you can just call the usual "linear model" function `lm()`.

### Using `lm()`

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x + z, data = your_data_frame)
summary(fit)
```

### Using matrix algebra

In contrast, you can also take the more pretentious route of coding the matrix algebra to fit these parameters manually. This involves no packages, other than base R.

```
X <- as.matrix(your_data[, c('x', 'z')]) # extract your predictors
X <- cbind(1, X) # add an intercept to your design matrix
y <- your_data$y

betas <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y
```

**EDIT**: Note that these approaches assume no missing data (i.e., that every row has a y, x, and z value).

Comment: Thank you for this comment, I have an additional question. Should  the number of observations for all variables be equal?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include that concern. Yes, all variables must have equal (and complete / non-missing) observations. More complex techniques exist that don't have this requirement, but you would need a package to handle that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you suggest such package which deals with regression of different variable length. I am interested in performing regression of time series with different frequencies. For example quarter and monthly data.

Comment: Depending on your assumptions, **multiple imputation** with the `mice` package might be a good place to start.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I will come back to you if I am un able to solve the matter.

Comment: I'm grateful for the confidence you have in me, but you probably should not come back to me here. It would be most helpful if you open a new question (if you have one), which will be easier for other people to see and therefor help with. It will also be more helpful to other people who might have the same question you do.